# Random space characters were added in mailing

Tags: civimail, mosaico

I have sent a newsletter yesterday using a Mosaico template. The final mail had arbitrary space characters, where one of them landed in one of the urls and render that url garbage. The spaces are not in the database, I'm not sure where to check to see when and which component added them...

Base: Drupal 8, Civicrm 5.29.1

I'm pasting the html from a gmail client, as showwed original. It seems the space character is among a newline as well, as this part is actually is a single line. And new line shows how link is dead.

```
<p style="Margin: 1em 0px; Margin-bottom: 0px;">Patlamanın ardından hafızalaştırmaya yönelik ilk çaba, P24’ün “Barış Portreleri” projesiydi. 2019’da ise TMMOB, DİSK, KESK, TTB ve 10 Ekim Derneği tarafından “Emek, Barış ve Demokrasi Anıt Meydanı Anma Yeri Uluslararası Fikir ve Tasarım Projesi Yarışması” düzenlendi. Hafıza Merkezi’nden Banu Tuna, yarışmayı “Zamansız Kabuk/Bitmemiş Hikâyeler” projesiyle kazanan Caps Mimarlık’tan <a href="https://paydas.hafiza-merkezi.org/civicrm/mail
 ing/url?u=812&amp;qid=48310" rel='nofollow' target="_blank" style="color: #e4854b; color: #e4854b; text-decoration: none;">Pınar Kesim Aktaş ile konuştu</a>: “<em>O duygu yoğunluğunu her gün yaşamak istemeyen kişi kendini ister istemez duyarsızlaştırır. Bu durumda tasarladığınız mekân bir boşluğa dönüşür. Ya da duygu yoğunluğuna dayanamayıp oradan geçmekten kaçınır. O zaman da kapalı bir kutu tasarlamış olursunuz. Acının başka bir tarifini bulursak, insanlar rahatsızlık duymadan hafızayı yaşamaya ve yaşatmaya devam edebilir.</em>”</p>
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to show examples of the HTML?

Comment: Thanks, did it.

Comment: I've never seen anything like this in 10 years of CiviCRM use or 19 years of mail administration.  If the spaces aren't in the database, I would look at the mail headers and see if there are any servers in the path that might have altered the email - spam filtering servers, for instance.

Comment: I haven't see it in the database but I've checked via phpmyadmin and maybe I've missed the line breaks in the text. You can't be more right about it.

Comment: Today it happened again. I'm still looking at in phpmyadmin but I copy the mailing content and paste in plain text editor (Atom) and don't see any space but when I send the mailing, there is a stupid space in between a random word. They're not there when I check the HTML view in test modal (as I don't see them in the database)...